# length of column across all tables in a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

How to get the max column size of common column like 'id' across all tables in the Mysql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH from information_schema.columns where column_name='id' order by 3;

use this

it will  solve this problem